# Townhall meeting details

Tags: discussion

It's been suggested a few times to have a townhall meeting in the chat at some point, to maybe clarify some of the FAQs, decide on some site directions, maybe add some more guidelines for tags, flags, deletions, comments etc.

- So on that note, what time/day of the week (GMT time) works best for you, IF  you'd attend?
- and regardless, what topic/question would you like brought up in such a discussion?

Comment: Why is this question suddenly on top?

Comment: I suspect it was when Community removed the [tag:featured] tag.

Answer (score -1):

As proposed - I suggest to ban political messages on this site. Specifically, messages of hate such as [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1712/halabi).

While posts and comments can be flagged/edited/deleted, profiles may be used (and abused) to promote inappropriate, offensive, and outright illegal views, claims and messages.

It would be easier for us to help each other and others, if politics were not involved in the considerations when writing/commenting/up/downvoting questions and answers on this site.

Comment: Moderators can be notified e.g. via chat. However, note that in general, [rules regarding profiles are rather permissive](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/31209/149942). Questions, answers, and comments are subject to much more scrutiny.

Comment: `<rant>`[Why shouldn't we use the word 'here' in a textlink](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100/why-shouldnt-we-use-the-word-here-in-a-textlink)`</rant>` (applies to "this", "that", "there" too)